# Carousel slider with WP_Query to show 3 posts on each slide

Tags: wp-query, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap carousel to show 3 posts on each slide. But my code is showing only a single item on each slide.

**Here is my code:**

```
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div id="popular-services" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <!-- Start Carousel Indicator Loop -->
                        <?php if ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) : while ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) : $popular_services->the_post(); ?>
                        <li data-target="#popular-services" data-slide-to="<?php echo $popular_services->current_post; ?>" class="<?php if ( $popular_services->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?> text-primary"></li>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    </ol>
                    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> 
                        <?php if ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) : while ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) : $popular_services->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="carousel-item <?php if ( $popular_services->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <?php
                                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'card-img-top') );
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <?php echo the_title('<h5 class="card-title">', '</h5>'); ?>
                                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo my_custom_excerpt(20); ?></p> 
                                                <?php echo my_custom_read_more('Learn More'); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What changes do I need to make in order to get it working as per my need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your first code with solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite your question is a generic PHP programming problem, what you're trying to do can be achieved like so, where the key is the `$i` which is a custom `while` counter:

```php
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php if ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) :
        $i = 0; // add this counter
        while ( $popular_services->have_posts() ) : $popular_services->the_post();
        ?>
            <?php if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php if ( $popular_services->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <div class="row">
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    your code here
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if ( $i % 3 === 2 ) : ?>
                    </div><!-- .row -->
                </div><!-- .carousel-item -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; // increment the counter
        endwhile;
        ?>
        <!-- This is needed if the (<number of posts> / 3) does not equal to 3. E.g. 11 posts would require 4 rows -->
        <?php if ( $i % 3 !== 0 ) : ?>
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- .carousel-item -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; // end have_posts() ?>
</div>
```

I hope that helps and you're able to see the `$i` parts and implement it properly in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Sally CJ for your reply. Yes, this was a generic PHP problem. And since I am new to web development I keep making minor mistakes. I had already tried the counter but it didn't work. So I removed the counter. I figured it out after your reply that I had made a mistake while using the counter on my own. Instead of putting `<div class="row">` inside the counter condition, I put it outside. As a result it nested the `row` inside `col-lg-4`.

Comment: I can understand that, but for questions like this, they're better off asked on Stack Overflow. :) But anyway, I'm glad the answer helped. ;)

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks again.